# Make a parametrized data type instance of Semigroup

Tags: haskell, types, semigroup

I want to make the data type `Moneda` a instance of the Semigroup, and implement the associative operation as `+`. I'm having difficulties understanding it properly.

The working solution I found, is the following:

```
data Moneda a = RON Double | EUR Double deriving (Show)

instance Num a => Num (Moneda a) where
    (RON x) + (RON y) = RON (x + y)
    (RON x) + (RON y) = RON (x + y)

instance Semigroup (Moneda a) where
    (<>) = (+)
```

I couldn't understand why exactly the below aproach is failing and how it's possible to make it work without making `Moneda` a `Num` instance.

```
data Moneda a = RON a | EUR a deriving (Show)

instance Semigroup (Moneda a) where
    (<>) (RON a) (RON b) = (RON a+b) -- fails, please see error below
vs 
    (<>) (RON a) (RON b) = (RON a) -- works but doesn't help me because I need the a+b sum  

-- cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Moneda a 
-- In the second argument of `(+)', namely `b'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you try to add a value of type `Moneda a` to a value of type `a` in your implementation of `(<>)`. That is you wrote `(RON a+b)` which parses as `(RON a) + b` (because function/constructor application binds stronger than addition). You probably meant to write `RON (a + b)` as in:

```
data Moneda a = RON a | EUR a deriving (Show)

instance Semigroup (Moneda a) where
  (<>) (RON a) (RON b) = RON (a + b)
```

But that won't work either as it requires addition to be defined on the type to which you apply `Moneda`. So, for your definition to make sense you will need to constrain the instantiation of the type argument `a` to types in `Num`:

```
data Moneda a = RON a | EUR a deriving (Show)

instance Num a => Semigroup (Moneda a) where
  RON a <> RON b = RON (a + b)
  EUR a <> EUR b = EUR (a + b)
```

For example:

```
> RON 2 <> RON 3
RON 5
```

Note that this definition of `(<>)` is only partial. It does not account for adding values built with `RON` to values built with `EUR`:

```
> RON 5 <> EUR 7
*** Exception: Main.hs:(4,3)-(5,30): Non-exhaustive patterns in function <>
```

So, you still have to write code that deals with those cases.

Comment: How about  `RON a <> EUR b`..? I believe this can not be a simple addition function plus has to obey associativity rule.

Comment: @Redu. No, that depends on the meaning that is given to `RON` and `EUR` of course.

Comment: Right sure.. but something makes me guess one of them is Romanian Leu and the other one is Euro.

Comment: @Redu Then I know how to write that function. On days that the exchange rate of the Leu happens to be 1 EUR at least. ;-)

Comment: RON and EUR are currency names and I convert between using `Functor` and a convertion function.

Comment: @MihaiB. That's not how you are "supposed" to use `Functor`. That is, `fmap` should not change the constructor; the equality `fmap id = id` should hold. But I guess we are drifting off topic as far as the original question is concerned...

Comment: @StefanHoldermans Good point. I'm actually thinking on how to make `Moneda` a Monoid instance and having some issues. `mempty` should be something like `EUR 0` or `RON 0` but that is not possible, would be 2 identities. I'm thinking to change the declaration of type to `data Moneda a = RON a | EUR a | Empty a deriving (Show)`  , then using `mempty = Empty 0`. That might get me in other problems ...

Comment: @Milah B. That's better but you don't need to parametrize `Empty` It's just the identity against all currencies. However.. the real thing is, what's the idea behind making your currency type an instance of Monoid..?

Comment: The purpose is was to see the currencies as different goups and build a model starting from this. Each group would have an functions that I can add, substract and echange e.g. `exchangeEur :: Double -> Double\n
exchangeEur = exchangeWithConvRate 4.3` - exchangeWithConvRate is a curried func. To have a `functor` between this goups I needed a common _data constructor_ , so that I decided not have _ron_ and _eur_ as separate data types. Do you have any suggestion on how would you would aproach this but respecting the initial idea: seeing the data model as groups? Any suggestion is welcomed @Redu